# Rails 3 + Devise: How do I set a "Universal" password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Rails 3 with Devise. Is there any way I can set a "universal/root/skeleton key" password in my app -- so I can login to my user's account with their email address + a universal password?

p.s: This is probably a really bad authentication practice, but for some reason I need to edit some of my users.

Comment: From a security point of view this is crazy! Can't you just make an admin interface to perform whatever it is you need to do with the users?

Comment: You should make an admin user and just give him proper permissions to edit other users.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is highly NOT recommended.

The way to do it is define Roles for your users, and add an interface from which a user with a certain role can edit something.

If you still want to do it your way, probably the best way to do it would be to extend `DatabaseAuthenticatable` like this

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module DatabaseAuthenticatable
      def valid_password?(incoming_password)
        password_digest(incoming_password) == self.encrypted_password or incoming_password == "your_universal_password_here"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

you can put this in your initializers folder (create for example an `add_universal_password.rb` file, and write that down)

But I say again, this idea is not ok

Comment: Thank you. Totally bad idea I know. Just going to do this quick hack, some quick editing and switch back.

Answer (score 0):

Extending `DatabaseAuthenticable` as in the answer by Andrei S is a bit brittle, because it makes your code assume some implementation details of Devise's `valid_password?` method. A less brittle way would be to override the `valid_password?` method in the model that mixes in `DatabaseAuthenticatable` (e.g. `User`) and call `super()`, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticable
...
  def valid_password?(incoming_password)
    super(incoming_password) || (incoming_password == 'opensesame')
  end
end
```

Comment: How does `super` find a redefined method? The super class is ActiveRecord::Base, not a Devise class. Devise was included/monkey-patched/mixed in.